# Adding NgRx with Nx MFE cause Unable to evaluate this expression statically

Tags: angular, ngrx, nrwl-nx, nrwl, angular-ngrx-data

Adding NgRx to the Nx MFE angular application cause the below issue, removing the generated files issue is not there

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    .........
    StoreModule.forRoot(
      { product: productStateReducer },
      {
        metaReducers: !environment.production ? [] : [],
        runtimeChecks: {
          strictActionImmutability: true,
          strictStateImmutability: true,
        },
      }
    ),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    !environment.production ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25 }) : [],
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The issue is with `!environment.production`

```
    apps/host/src/app/app.module.ts:43:6
    43     !environment.production
            ~~~~~~~~~~~
    Unable to evaluate this expression statically.
  apps/host/src/environments/environment.ts:19:28
    19 export const environment = new EnvironmentImpl();
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This syntax is not supported.
```

Initial setup

```
nx g @nrwl/angular:ngrx host --module=apps/host/src/app/app.module.ts --root
```

environment.ts

```
class EnvironmentImpl {
  production = false;
}
export const environment = new EnvironmentImpl();
```